# Url rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php

How can i redirect
from https://www.example.org/conference/id to https://www.example.org/conferences in .htaccess

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways about making that. Here is one:

Creating a conferences.php file then create a folder "conferences" and a file id.(html) or (php).
Open the id.php and paste this code

```
header('Location: /conferences');
```

if you want to use .htaccess, just add this:

```
RewriteRule ^conferences/?$ conferences/id.php [L]
```